# nested html <script> tag's leads to display javascript code on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html page in which I am embedding small html block which contain script tags . Now because of script tag's inside the embedded code main html file is not able to recognise script tag's inside the main html file which tends to display the javascript code on UI. Following is the code sample which is giving problem. Please help me for the same.

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js">

     << Embedded HTML Code >>
      -var modules = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><script></script></head><body>Swapnil C</body></html>"

      << JAVASCRIPT CODE which is getting displayed on browser >>

  </script>


   <div class="container">
      <div class="top-section">
         <form action="#">
            <div class="webpage-container"></div>
         </form>
         <div class="thanks">
            <h2>Thank you!</h2>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Do you really require that nested `script` tag? Could you expand on and clarify the intention? This could be an *xy problem* and if this is the case an alternative approach may be better. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: *In addition to* the problem identified in the duplicate, you also need to escape the `</script>` tag in the embedded html to stop it ending the containing script element. Use `<\/script>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append javascript code and point a js file simultaneously. You should use separate  tag to do this.

Try It:

```
     <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"> </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">

      /* write your js code here.

          </script>

<< Embedded HTML Code here >>




           <div class="container">
              <div class="top-section">
                 <form action="#">
                    <div class="webpage-container"></div>
                 </form>
                 <div class="thanks">
                    <h2>Thank you!</h2>
                 </div>
              </div>

           </div>
          </body>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, but still issue is not resolved. could you please suggest me anything different.

Comment: See my modification. If it is not resolved, share your full code.